# VBA userform 2 commandbuttons + attribute value to variable

Tags: vba, userform, commandbutton

I only have basic VBA knowledge. Trying to find a way to make the user choice between two value "internal" or "external" then depending on the results it would run one part of the code or another part.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I have started to create a user form, but how can get back the value type_trade back into the sub and then use it for a if then statement?

```
Private Sub External_Click()
    Dim type_trade As String
    type_trade = "external" 
End Sub

Private Sub Internal_B2B_Click()
    Dim type_trade As String
    type_trade = "Internal_B2B"
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is as follows:

```
Private type_trade As String

Private Sub External_Click()
   type_trade = "external"
End Sub

Private Sub Internal_B2B_Click()
   type_trade = "Internal_B2B"
End Sub

Private Sub SomeOtherPoint()
   If type_trade = "Internal_B2B" Then
      'do something
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, it has helped me to figure out.